# Update a proactive message sent to user

Tags: botframework

Is it possible to update a proactive message sent to a user?

Scenario:
A message is sent to a user because a file was shared.
The file is now unshared which makes the previous message invalid so can I update the previous message or do I need to send a new one?

Regards,
Oskar

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: So this would be a private/personal message sent to the user

Comment: On what Bot Framework channel? Microsoft Teams?